# Setting value of radio buttons in Side by Side questions for Qualtrics - breaks in JFE but works in Standard

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have javascript that works in Qualtric as long it isn't the JFE engine.

[removed code]

The code basically is an alert and clears the radio buttons selected depending on what is already selected in the first column. I'm not sure why the JFE engine would break it but while we can set the individual values of a side by side radio button, you can't clear it.

.setvalue(null) does not seem to be a valid option.

I know nothing about javascript so any help would be much appreciated. The question type for Qualtrics is side by side, 2 sections, 1-8 columns in each section.

Answer (score 0):

This brings back memories...I've tried to do this before, but was unsuccessful. The problem is that in JFE setting the value of the radio button input field directly doesn't work. With a normal multiple choice or matrix question you can use the Qualtrics Question API (setChoiceValue,  setAnswerValue, etc.) to set the value in JFE.  Unfortunately, those don't work with a side-by-side question because there isn't a way to specify the applicable question in the side-by-side. At the time, I opened a case with Qualtrics Support, but never got a resolution.

If you REALLY need to do this, the work around is to not run the survey under JFE.  To do that, you can add the Q_JFE=0 parameter to your survey link or if you don't want to do that, just add a quota since quotas prevent JFE (at least last time I checked).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new option for inserting Javascript when running JFE: 
The default page now loads with

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});
```

I moved code that did not work properly with "addOnload" to "addOnReady" and now it runs without using the Q_JFE=0 parameter.

Comment: =( it still doesn't work for me - probably because I have javascript clearing questions choices.